# Advice on MongoDB hardware

Tags: mongodb, hardware

I currently have a databse which, according to MMS, use ~60GB in Memory (resident 50, virtual 55, mapped 0) and the "data size" is about 220GB and growing. The "DB Storage" is around 100GB and growing too.

The current machines where this database have 128GB of RAM and SSDs.

**I'd like to know if you think I'll have a lot of performance decrease, if I switch to a new machine with more RAM (256GB) but replace the SSDs by classic hard drives?**

I think that as long as the database fits in RAM, the performances won't be harmed, and I think also that MongoDB will be smart enough to load in RAM only the data used often (typically, the 3 months old data).

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB uses all available RAM for an LRU cache. If your working set fits in RAM you should be fine.

http://docs.mongodb.org/master/faq/diagnostics/#what-is-a-working-set